# Select a column (having foreign key) without joining two tables

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I want select a column (which has a foreign key constraint) without creating joins on tables. I have two tables named `eventupdate` and `eventcategory`. The `event` column is common in both tables. whenever I try the following code it gives an error.

Please give some suggestion. I don't want to create a join.

```
$qb2 = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

$from = 'Entities\EventCategory cat';

$qb2->add('from',$from)

    ->select('cat.event')

    ->Where('cat.id=3);

$query=$qb2->getQuery();
```

Comment: *"it gives an error..."* What is the error? Why do you use [the low level API](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#low-level-api) with `->add` and not the normal `->from` method...

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that I can see:

1. `HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS` together with `ArrayHydrator`

   ```
   $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
   $query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true);
   var_dump($query->getArrayResult()); // Will return array with raw foreign key column name => value, e.g. user_id => 5
   ```
2. Create separate property in `Entities\EventCategory` which has the foreign key as primitive type

   ```
   /**
    * @var User
    *
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
    * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
    */
   private $user;

   /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    */
   private $userId;
   ```